# Read file where first line is missing data

Tags: python, pandas

My input datafile has some label lines (e.g. "Alabama[edit]") interspersed with the desired data. Because the first line is one of these, pandas df.read_table() errors out on the subsequent lines regarding them as too long when I use a '(' as the delimiter.

The easy answer is to tell read_table to skip the first row, but that feels hacky.  Is there a way to tell pandas to read two columns even if it only gets data for one?

#### excerpted datafile

```
Alabama[edit] 
Auburn (Auburn University)[1] 
Florence (University of North Alabama) 
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2] 
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2] 
Troy (Troy University)[2] 
Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4] 
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5] 
Alaska[edit] 
Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
...
```

Comment: I do not see any issue with filtering the source file for valid records first.

Comment: In this specific case, I couldn't clean the input file before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  I needed to set column names and then it just worked.

```
    townsDF = pd.read_table('university_towns.txt', 
                        header=None, 
                        names=['RegionName', 'State'],
                        sep='(',
                        converters={'RegionName': str, 'State': str}
                       )
```

Output

```
RegionName  State
0   Alabama[edit]   

1   Auburn  Auburn University)[1]

2   Florence    University of North Alabama)

3   Jacksonville    Jacksonville State University)[2]
```